# How do I select DISTINCT for concatenating of a column grouping by another column?

Tags: sql-server

I have data like this

```
Party_Id    Account_Id  TR_Id
1           1           6
1           2           6
2           3           5
2           4           5
3           6           7
3           7           8
```

I want result like below

```
Party   Trading
1        6
2        5
3        7,8
```

Comment: Hints: `DISTINCT`, a derived table/CTE, and String Aggregation.

Comment: SELECT Party_Id , STRING_AGG(DISTINCT TR_Id) FROM Table

Comment: `DISTINCT` isn't a valid operator for `STRING_AGG`, and it requires 2 parameters (the string to aggregate, and the delimiter). This is why you need a derived table/CTE.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to perform any distincting separately:

```
SELECT Party = Party_Id, Trading = STRING_AGG(TR_Id, ',') 
FROM 
(
   SELECT Party_Id, TR_Id 
   FROM dbo.YourTableName 
   GROUP BY Party_Id, TR_Id
) AS x GROUP BY Party_Id;
```